# Why is my ListView rendering repeated items?

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

This is how I'm populating my `ListView`:

This is the scenario:

## 1 -  Creating two arrays

[image]

## 2 - Creating a RowItem class

```
  public class IconRow {

  private String title;
  private int icon;

  public IconRow(String title, int icon) {
      this.title = title;
      this.icon = icon;

  }
      public String getTitle() {
      return title;
  }

  public int getIcon() {
      return icon;
  }

}
```

## 3 - Creating a ListAdapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<IconRow> rowItem;
    String description;
    long option;

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<IconRow> rowItem, String description, long option)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItem = rowItem;
    this.description = description;
    this.option = option;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return rowItem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return rowItem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return rowItem.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_arrow, null);


        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        IconRow row_pos = rowItem.get(position);
        // setting the image resource and title
        imgIcon.setImageResource(row_pos.getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(row_pos.getTitle());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

## 4 - Creating a Row Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_go"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## 5 - Creating the List inside Fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parameters_settings, container, false);

        lv_settings_1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_settings_1);

        menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_lv_settings_1);
        menuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.arrow_icons);

        menu_iconRow = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < menutitles.length; i++) {
            IconRow items = new IconRow(menutitles[i], menuIcons.getResourceId(
                    i, -1));
            menu_iconRow.add(items);
        }

        adapter_settings_1 = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), menu_iconRow, "No Description", 0);

        lv_settings_1.setAdapter(adapter_settings_1);

        return rootView;
    }
```

### Problem

When using this method up to 7 or more items on the List, it starts to repeat and populate wrong. What's going on?

Comment: because everything is in the `if (convertView == null) {` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing this part of your adapter code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_arrow, null);
    }


    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    IconRow row_pos = rowItem.get(position);
    // setting the image resource and title
    imgIcon.setImageResource(row_pos.getIcon());
    txtTitle.setText(row_pos.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

The convert view is probably being reused with the old values

Answer (score 1):

Fix:
3 - Creating a ListAdapter

```
    public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_arrow, null);

    }
            ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            IconRow row_pos = rowItem.get(position);
            // setting the image resource and title
            imgIcon.setImageResource(row_pos.getIcon());
            txtTitle.setText(row_pos.getTitle());
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Read about ViewHolder.